# Acumatica REST API Filter on last modified date

Tags: rest, acumatica

I'm looking to create an integration and need to be able to extract data based on last modified date.  I have followed the example provided ([Acumatica StockItem example](https://help-2020r2.acumatica.com/(W(4))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=775ca16b-cba6-4c1d-89d5-c1df7833bfea)) but the Get always returns all stockitems.

I have modified one stockitem and since the filter in the example is for modified dates greater than a month ago this stockitem should be only one being returned.

Looking at the Content returned the issue would appear to be a "unrecognized" date format, but I have followed the example.

It would appear I'm missing something here but can't figure out what, any advise?

[Screen Capture of returned Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9GmO.png)

[JSON view of StockItem data being returned, modified item CONTABLE1 shows LastModified date of 2021-01-05](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbqh5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the value in the wrong format. You need to replace all the special codes like %3A and %2B with corresponding characters.

%3A is :
%2B is -

The below request is working without any issues.

```
http://localhost/ACU20193/entity/Default/20.200.001/StockItem?$top=5&$filter=LastModified gt datetimeoffset'2021-01-02T00:58:57.837-08:00'
```

Comment: Brilliant, removed the UrlEncode which left the : - characters in the parameter string and it worked. Thanks very much for your input....

Comment: @SteveW - Please mark this as answered by clicking the checkmark beside this answer.