# How to Add LastModifiedDate in Warehouse endpoint of ver 2022 R2 Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

[do not find LastModifiedDate in warehouse summary in warehouse endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlaUG.png) In Acumatica ver 2022-R2, endpoint of Warehouse I am trying to add LastModifiedDate for date filter by trying to use extended property but unable to do, please let me know how to do it.

I am trying to add LastModifiedDate for date filter by trying to use extended property of Acumatica endpoint of warehouse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fields that are present in the Data Access Class (DAC), but not visible on the screen, you need to manually type their name in the fields.

Usually for audit fields you can use the same mapped object as the top left most field on the screen, in this case Warehouse ID.

- Field Name : LastModifiedDateTime
- Mapped Object : Warehouse Summary
- Mapped Field : LastModifiedDateTime
- Field Type : DateTimeValue

Comment: do not find LastModifiedDate in warehouse summary of warehouse endpoint

Comment: My bad forgot to mention that for the mapped field you can type the field name if you know it is in the DAC even if it is not in the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to extend the endpoint in order to use lastmodifieddatetime to filter your request.  See this thread for a [test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65589385/acumatica-rest-api-filter-on-last-modified-date)